# git: svn is not a git command - Mac

Tags: git, git-svn

I had no issues yesterday but today I cannot run `git svn` anymore. It says:

```
git: 'svn' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar commands are
    fsck
    mv
    show
```

I don't know if it's relevant but since yesterday I updated `npm`(6.14.4) and `node` (v12.6.0).

I'm on macOs Catalina

Comment: Did you just update OS X or the command line tools?

Comment: @DaveNewton Not since yesterday, last month I think

Comment: `svn` is not built in to Git; you have to install `git-svn` separately, which adds `git-svn` which `git svn` invokes. Something may have un-added it, or it's not in your `$PATH` or something along those lines. Since it's not built in to Git, it's easy for these two to be uncoordinated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE: SEPTEMBER 2020**

It seems the end is here. Following the original suggestion will delete subversion forever. I found a [verified version of Subversion for MacOS](https://wandisco.com/source-code-management/subversion) and downloaded and installed it. I then needed to add Subversion to the `$PATH` variable to supersede Apple's `svn` (which just prints a message saying subversion is no longer included). To add it, add this line to your `~/.zprofile`:

```
export PATH=/opt/subversion/bin:$PATH
```

This will fix `svn`. I still have not figured out how to fix `git svn`.

**NB:** I also am aware that one can get subversion from `homebrew`, but `homebrew` is prohibited by my company's policies. If `homebrew` works better for somebody, please post your results here.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER: MARCH 2020**

Same thing happened to me today. After software update, `git svn` and `svn` are gone. It seems that [Apple is deprecating Subversion in XCode:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_release_notes)

> Command line tool support for Subversion — including svn, git-svn, and related commands — is no longer provided by Xcode. If you need Subversion or related command line tools, install the Command Line Tools package by running xcode-select --install. (50266910)

In the mean time, I was able to resolve this situation by deleting the XCode command line tools and reinstalling them:

```
sudo rm -Rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

After that, `git svn` and `svn` were back. Hopefully that will give us a stay of execution before final deprecation and deletion.

Comment: as of July this doesn't seem to work for me anymore.

Comment: @Reece, I updated my answer to reflect my latest experiences.

Comment: thanks - in the end I abandoned os x for this purpose & spun up a centos 7 instance which handled the task without issue.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to BitByteDog for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72930616/1260976).

I encountered this problem again under the macOS Ventura v13.1, and solved the problem by installing git-svn.

```
brew install git-svn
```

Below is the original answer.

---

I found a simple fixed solution for `macOS Big Sur v11.1 (20C69)` on [GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/52490#issuecomment-658239604).

1. make sure install git, svn, perl with brew.

   ```
   brew install git
   brew install perl
   brew install subversion
   ```
2. edit `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.0/libexec/git-core/git-svn`.

   replace `#!/usr/bin/perl` with `#!/usr/local/bin/perl`
3. `git svn` works.

---

The above solution only works under perl 5.32.0.

When I updated the perl to 5.32.1, `git svn` can no longer work.

> Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC (you may need to install the SVN::Core module)...

I found a solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/52490#issuecomment-757077535).

> Now subversion built with system perl, so we can add an environment
> variable to solve this problem:
>
> ```
> export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/#{perl_version}/darwin-thread-multi-2level
> ```
>
> You should replace `#{perl_version}` with system perl's version.
>
> For macOS Big Sur:
>
> ```
> export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
> ```

Comment: On my Mac, this worked for solving this problem: `git: 'svn' is not a git command.`, but then the `Can't locate SVN/Core.pm` error comes. You're still getting a +1 from me for getting me closer. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek I added a new solution, hope it helps you.

Comment: If you're getting `signal 11` when running this, it's likely because the `perl` runtime being called is not the same as the library being linked.  Be sure to run `/usr/local/bin/perl --version` (or whatever binary + `--version`) and check that the version number matches.  It turns out I needed to use `/usr/bin/perl` for it to be the 5.30.x version on my Big Sur install.

Answer (score 4):

1. First install git and svn with brew

```
brew install git
brew install svn
```

2. Use system default perl at `/usr/bin/perl`

if you installed perl with brew, please uninstall it.

`brew uninstall perl`

use `which perl` to check if using the system default perl at `/usr/bin/perl`. Make sure the git-svn use the `#!/usr/bin/perl`
use following command to check which perl is git-svn using

```
$ head -1 $(brew --prefix)/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

3. check you svn's perl version at `/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.14.1/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.4`
4. If you got error `Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC`
   you also need to set PERL5LIB path, for Catalina:

`export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level`

for Big Sur:

`export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level`

Reference: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/52490

Comment: thanks, your answer helped me to solve the problem on big sur

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem after upgrading macOS from version 10.15 (Catalina) to 10.15 (Big Sur).

Thank you very much for your answer [jqgsninimo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65602702/7828069). Those 3 steps took me 99% of the way. But then I got the error

> Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC (you may need to install the SVN::Core module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.0/share/perl5 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.28 /Network/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.28 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.28.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.28 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.28) at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.0/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.0/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
> Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.0/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 25.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.0/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 32.
> Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.0/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 23.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.0/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 23.

If anyone else experiences the same problem, the solution for me was to run this command

```
export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

I found the commands from
[this GitHub answer](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/52490#issuecomment-757077535)

Comment: Worked for me as a solution right after the solution by jqgsninimo. Now, I'm getting: `error: git-svn died of signal 11`, but that's probably related to something wrong with the svn dump itself.

Comment: Same error here, @ChristiaanWesterbeek. But even "git svn help" fails, so I don't think it is a problem with the svn dump. Have you solved your case?

Comment: No, I finally gave up. But another dev got it working. I propose to use a sledge hammer here and try another computer

Answer (score 2):

On Monterey, it was just:

```
brew install git-svn
```